# Slowdown on tensorflow convolutional network with custom parameter update

Tags: convolution, tensorflow, slowdown

I'm trying to implement a custom parameter update on a convolutional network, but every mini batch executed gets slower and slower.

I realize that there's no need to go through this trouble with a fixed learning rate, but I plan to update this later.

I call this in a loop where the feed_dict is the mini_batch.

```
sess.run(layered_optimizer(cost,.1,1),feed_dict = feed_dict)
```

where

```
def layered_optimizer(cost,base_rate, rate_multiplier):

    gradients = tf.gradients(cost, [*weights, *biases])
    print(gradients)

    #update parameters based on gradients: var = var - gradient * base_rate * multiplier
    for i in range(len(weights)-1):
        weights[i].assign(tf.subtract(weights[i], tf.multiply(gradients[i], base_rate * rate_multiplier)))
        biases[i].assign(tf.subtract(biases[i], tf.multiply(gradients[len(weights)+i], base_rate * rate_multiplier)))



    return(cost)
```

I'm not sure if this is has to do with the problem, but after trying to run the code a second time I get the following errors and have to restart.

could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
error retrieving driver version: Unimplemented: kernel reported driver version not implemented on Windows
could not destroy cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
Check failed: stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms( conv_parameters.ShouldIncludeWinogradNonfusedAlgo(), &algorithms)

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that every time this gets called

> gradients = tf.gradients(cost, [*weights, *biases])

a new instance of tf.gradients gets created, taking up unnecessary memory.